# player destroyed when touches the coin problem in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I,m Creating a simple endless runner project in unity. Im facing the unwanted error.
The player is getting destroyed when he touches the coin.
the coin is not getting destroyed and score is not counting.
here is the player script.
please fix this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator myani;
    Rigidbody myrb;
    public Text scoretext;
    int score = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myani = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myrb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        scoretext.text = "score"+score;
           
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x == 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 2, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x == 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 2, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x == -2)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 2, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x == 2)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 2, 0.5f, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            myani.SetTrigger("Roll");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            myani.SetTrigger("Jump");


        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.End))
        {
            myani.SetTrigger("Run 1");
        } 
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && myrb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            myrb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 5f, 0);
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "coin")
        {
            scoretext.text = "Score"+score;
            score+=1;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
           SceneManager.LoadScene("Game over");
            Destroy(gameObject);    


    
    }


}
```

The player has to collect the coin and it need to be destroyed

Comment: add some brackets to the last if statement

Answer (score 2):

Add some brakets to the lower if statement because this is currently always beeing called:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

If an if statement does not have brakets only the next line is in the if statement. the Destroy(gamobject) line will always be called if the function is executed destroying whatever is stored in gemeObject, i guess your player.

this should fix it:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
{
   SceneManager.LoadScene("Game over");
   Destroy(gameObject); 
}
```

Comment: thank you sir. another problem arised. the coin is not getting destroyed when touched and the score is not counting

Comment: use your debugger and see if  if (other.gameObject.tag == "coin") is ever triggered, i guess your coin is not tagged "coin"

Comment: also you should inkrement the score before you set the .text, otherwise the score will lag behind by one.

Comment: @chakri108 The coin probably is not tagged "coin" and you draw the score before you add 1 to it.